# How to write MATLAB functions in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: matlab, function, ipython, jupyter-notebook

### Overview

I am using the [MATLAB kernel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matlab_kernel) in Jupyter Notebook. I would like to write a function in the notebook, rather than referring to a function that is saved in another `.m` file. The problem is that when I try to do so, I get the error:

> Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.

### Visual example:

In a new notebook, it looks like the following picture:

[image]

Now, it does work if I make a new `.m` file:

[image]

and then call then function via the notebook:

[image]

but this is inconvenient. Is there a way to define functions from within a Jupyter Notebook directly?

### My software

- MATLAB 2017b
- Windows 10
- Jupyter running in chrome
- Jupyter installed via anaconda

Comment: This looks like a limitation of the MATLAB kernel. If you look at the [kernel source](https://github.com/Calysto/matlab_kernel/), you can see that they're [using `eval`](https://github.com/Calysto/matlab_kernel/blob/master/matlab_kernel/kernel.py#L259), which doesn't accept function definitions. For example, if you try `eval('function trialcode() asdf = 1; end')` in MATLAB you'll receive the same error.

Comment: Evil `eval` has done it again!

Comment: @buzjwa As Mermaid Man would say, [`EEEEVAAAAAALLLLL!!!`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCfTon-GB2I)

Answer (score 16):

The [documentation](https://am111.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jmatlab_use.html#User-defined-functions) indicates that you can use the magic:

```
%%file name_of_your_function.m
```

To take your example, your cell should be written as follows:

```
%%file fun.m

function out = fun(in)
    out = in + 1;
end
```

This creates a new file called `fun.m`. This allows MATLAB to do what it needs (a function in a separate file), and also allows you to write your function directly in the Jupyter Notebook.